# Error in Multiple Linear Regression in Python with sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, linear-regression

I am trying to perform a Multiple Linear Regression for a dataset. I have prepared the dataset, train_test_split is finished and when I tried to fit the model to the linear regressor, I get the following error:

[image: Error in the program - image]

I am also attaching the code below. Please take a look and help me solve the error.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

dataset = pd.read_csv('50_Startups.csv');

dataset.head()

x = dataset.iloc[:,:-1]
y = dataset.iloc[:,:4]

states = pd.get_dummies(x['State'], drop_first=True)

states.head()

x = x.drop('State', axis=1)

x.head()

x = pd.concat([x, states], axis=1)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =  train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Looks like you didn't really drop the state column.

Comment: @pavel It did drop the state column. I really checked once again and the column is dropped.

Comment: The error is triggered by a string 'Florida'. Which other column can it be?

Comment: Why are you using `drop_first`?

Comment: Yup, but, all the state categories are encoded already.

Comment: drop_first=True is important to use, as it helps in reducing the extra column created during dummy variable creation. Hence it reduces the correlations created among dummy variables

Comment: I suggest you search your dataframe and find out where "Florida" lives.

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: Somewhere in your dataframe a string "Florida" (and potentially others too) exists. You need to find out why it's still there and get rid of whatever column contains strings.

Comment: My dataset is a startup dataset. So, most of the columns are just number saying the expenditure in various fields and the only column with categorical features is the "State". And that column is also encoded and I have verified it and it is encoded.

Comment: Ok, I will do that and will get back to you in a moment.

Comment: The error suggests that it's still there.

Comment: @paval Nope, the total rows in the dataset are only 50, and I have gone through all the rows after encoding these categorical features with 0s and 1s. There is no Florida, present.

Comment: @paval, I have solved the error myself. everything was correct, the only mistake I did or the computer did was, it did not append the states properly to the new dataframe. Now, It is done and the regressor is properly functioning.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please **re-read** [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely "***DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question*" (emphasis in the original).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include any necessary source code, data, and error messages as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting error because you choose Y value (target value) wrong.
This will work -

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

dataset = pd.read_csv('50_Startups.csv');
dataset.head()

x = dataset.iloc[:,:-1]
y = dataset['Profit']

x = pd.get_dummies(dataset, prefix=['State'])


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =  train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Comment: This will work too, but, I have solved the error myself. It was not properly appending the newly encoded states column. Thanks anyway.